# Count number of English words in string in R

Tags: r, nlp

I would like to count the number of English words in a string of text.

```
df.words <- data.frame(ID = 1:2,
              text = c(c("frog friend fresh frink foot"),
                       c("get give gint gobble")))

df.words

  ID                         text
1  1 frog friend fresh frink foot
2  2         get give gint gobble
```

I'd like the final product to look like this:

```
  ID                         text count
1  1 frog friend fresh frink foot     4
2  2         get give gint gobble     3
```

I'm guessing I'll have to first separate based on spaces and then reference the words against a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, separate (`strsplit(., "\\s+")`) and then reference against a dictionary (perhaps using `%in%`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @r2evans suggestion of using `strsplit()` and using a random English word .txt file dictionary [online](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words), example is below. This solution probably might not scale well if you have a large number of comparisons because of the `unnest` step.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# text file with 479k English words ~4MB
dict <- read.table(file = url("https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/raw/master/words_alpha.txt"), col.names = "text2")

df.words <- data.frame(ID = 1:2,
                       text = c(c("frog friend fresh frink foot"),
                                c("get give gint gobble")),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df.words %>% 
  mutate(text2 = strsplit(text, split = "\\s")) %>% 
  unnest(text2) %>% 
  semi_join(dict, by = c("text2")) %>% 
  group_by(ID, text) %>% 
  summarise(count = length(text2))
```

Output

```
     ID text                         count
  <int> <chr>                        <int>
1     1 frog friend fresh frink foot     4
2     2 get give gint gobble             3
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R alternative, using EJJ's great recommendation for `dict`:

```r
sapply(strsplit(df.words$text, "\\s+"),
       function(z) sum(z %in% dict$text2))
# [1] 4 3
```

I thought that this would be a clear winner in speed, but apparently doing `sum(. %in% .)` one at a time can be a little expensive. (It is slower *with this data*.)

Faster but not necessarily simpler:

```r
words <- strsplit(df.words$text, "\\s+")
words <- sapply(words, `length<-`, max(lengths(words)))
found <- array(words %in% dict$text2, dim = dim(words))
colSums(found)
# [1] 4 3
```

It's a hair faster (~ 10-15%) than EJJ's solution, so likely only a good thing if you need to wring some performance out of it.

(Caveat: EJJ's is faster with this 2-row dataset. If the data is 1000x larger, then my first solution is a little faster, and my second solution is twice as fast. Benchmarks are benchmarks, though, don't optimize code beyond usability if speed/time is not a critical factor.)

Comment: this is cool to see using arrays, also thanks for confirming my suspicion with performance